# What is the meaning of "Localization native development region" entry in info.plist?

Tags: ios, info.plist

I don't know if I really understood the function of the "Localization native development region" entry in info.plist file.

Somewhere I read that this entry allows to specify the app language when there is no matching with a language resource dir.

I have an app localized in three languages: english, italian and spanish (en.lproj, it.lproj and es.lproj) and I set "Localization native development region" entry to Italy. When I change the language and locale in "Settings" (for example by chosing the arabic language and a proper region), the app language is english. Shouldn't be it italian as I set "Localization native development region" to Italy in the info.plist?

Any ideas? Could it be tied to the AppStore app description language?

Comment: For some reason, changing this value changes the language of GameCenter interface accessed through app. I'm not sure those GameCenter controllers are properly internationalized by Apple or how that is supposed to work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the CFBundle documentation:

> kCFBundleDevelopmentRegionKey
>   The name of the development language of the bundle.
>   When CFBundle looks for resources, the fallback is to look in the lproj whose name is given by the kCFBundleDevelopmentRegionKey in the Info.plist file. You must, therefore, ensure that a bundle contains an lproj with that exact name containing a copy of every localized resource, otherwise CFBundle cannot guarantee the fallback mechanism will work.
>   Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>   Declared in CFBundle.h.

No relation to the AppStore Description language.

Answer (score 6):

I resolved using the settings below.

[image: Settings]

Comment: Is this allowed or will this be rejected upon submission to the app store?

Answer (score 2):

The native development region also sets the default language spoken by VoiceOver. If you set this correctly you won't have to override the accessibility language in all the default components used in your app (which fall back to English).