# Iphone Application in languages other than English

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store, nslocalizedstring

I am new iPhone application development. So please go easy with me :)

I want to write my application in Swedish. When i started writing my app, i hard coded the swedish words.

for example, in the for the navigationBar title (contact us)

```
self.title=@"Kontakta oss";
```

Is it permitted by Apple? What if the person reviewing my app in AppStore does not know Swedish. How does things work?

Sorry for being a noob here. 
Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hey it's better if you create a localization file that renders the content in swedish when the language is changed to swedish. If you want to know more please come back. I can quickly guide you as to how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be perfectly fine. You just need an English description for the AppStore as well.

Comment: Sorry. canot understand your second line :(

Comment: @Eiko By description you mean, explaining the App during submission? So i dont have to change anything in the project now..is it?

Comment: @Narayanan You don't need to change anything in the project now. It is just when uploading, you need to provide the product info (meta data) that can be read in iTunes/AppStore in English as well. Also, you should set the language in your project correctly as Swedish (I think there's something in the info.plist file or project settings).

Comment: @Eiko Thanks for your reply. The product info (meta data) is just a description about the project is it? Like explaining the App and what can be done with the App.

Comment: Yes, basically it's what you see when using the store.

Comment: One last question. How do i set the language of the application to swedish. I know there is an option while we submit it. Is that what you mean ? I did not see any such option in Project settings

Comment: In your Info.plist file there's something called "Localization native development region". Not sure if there was anything else to do - it will be obvious when adding the product in iTunes backend.

Comment: I checked "Localization native development region", but the option "Swedish" was not listed at all

Comment: Hmm... coming to the end of my knowledge here. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005236/what-is-the-meaning-of-localization-native-development-region-entry-in-info-pli is of help.

Comment: @Eiko what if i want the description also to be in Swedish for users to see from the app store?

Comment: You can add languages in iTunesConnect backend when you upload the binary. Don't worry - it will all be quite obvious. :)