# Choosing localization for unsupported languages

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, internationalization

I have localizations for "en" and "ru" languages, and if user select any other language (fr,de...) I need to display Russian localization variant. I tried changing "Localization native development region" in info.plist to "ru" / "Russian", but it always displays English, when using unsupported language. [There is related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005236/what-is-the-meaning-of-localization-native-development-region-entry-in-info-pli) from which I'm assuming this task is impossible.

I would be grateful for any advice and insights on these issues.

Comment: The crash is probably just Xcode 4. It crashes a lot no matter what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, Xcode 4 crashes a lot, but on this task it crashes every time I try to add image localization. I need Xcode 3?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have the very same problem and can loclaize my Default.png's for the iPad!!!

Comment: @Icky, I think that's just Xcode bug. I didn't try localization since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with my solution posted here

[Localizing strings in iOS: default (fallback) language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263859/localizing-strings-in-ios-default-fallback-language/8784451#8784451)

It is possible to set any non-English as default too. Even if the current device is not set to be using that language (eg. Russian).

You can use `[UIImage imageNamed:L(@"AN_IMAGE")]`

Then in *different* `Localizable.strings` file, set to different values:

```
"AN_IMAGE" = "some_image_default.png";
"AN_IMAGE" = "some_image_ru.png";
"AN_IMAGE" = "some_image_pt.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have read [String Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6) from Apple how to create a Localizable.strings file for every needed language. You can use than `NSLocalizedString` to enter the localized string to every needed file and don't have to translate every file.

Comment: Yes, I did, and localized strings are working very well. Localized nibs are working too, despite the fact that they are scattered all over subfolders.
But I need to load localized image files... so that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Condor:

I have similar issues you have had with localized pictures with localized XIB files. They show up fine with the translation in XCode and my app works well with localization in the Simulator. It's just on the device where I always see plain english for the XIB parts... (All copy translated with NSLocalizedString() works fine on the simulator.

Took the smallest possible example project and implemented similar folder structure there - no problem...